# I have an array fetched from a database column, for each of the item separated by \n\r, I want to move the next item to a new line

Tags: php

$array is an array gotten from database as:
**$array:** 'State.\r\nLga. \r\n City '

I have tried with:

```
$array = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $array);
```

But I am still getting output as

//Array

How do I break the items into a new line and prevent it from outputting 'Array' as the result?

Answer (score 0):

you could use php builtin function nl2br(), It inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string. You can check example in [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) or [w3school.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp)

Comment: Okay, thank you. Had it done before the reply came. Thanks a lot